# Why is apache running as root?

Tags: apache-http-server

Isn't apache supposed to only bind to port `80` as `root` but then switch to `www-data` user to handle request. I currently have an `access.log` file whose perminisons are `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1312 Jan  9 08:23 access.log`, if I am correct then the `www-data` user shouldnt be able to write to this `access.log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# ps auxf
USER         PID  COMMAND
root         542  /usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
http         592   \_ /usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
http         593   \_ /usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
http         594   \_ /usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
http        3121   \_ /usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND
```

Apache has support for live configuration reloads as well as 'graceful' restarts. For this to work, the "master" process needs to continue running as root so that it could possibly bind to new ports, re-read TLS key files, and so on.

However, requests are handled by Apache *worker* processes – and these never run as root. They are only able to log files because they've inherited an *already opened* file descriptor for "access.log" from the master process.

(Access rights are always checked at open time, not at write time, in order to allow exactly this usage as well as to disallow possible privilege escalations.)